# separator doesn't work while reading csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have data which consists 3004 rows without header, and each row has different number of fields (e.g. for row number 1,2,3,4 has 16,17,21,12, respectively). Here is my code when I call the csv.

```
 df = pd.read_csv(file,'rb', delimiter ='\t', engine='python')
```

here is the output:

```
$GPRMC,160330.40,A,1341.,N,10020.,E,0.006,,150517,,,A*7D
$GPGGA,160330.40,1341.,N,10020.,E,1,..
$PUBX,00,160330.40,1341.,N,10020.,E,...
$PUBX,03,20,2,-,056,40,,000,5,U,014,39,41,026,...
$PUBX,04,160330.40,150517,144210.39,1949,18,-6...
ÿ$GPRMC,160330.60,A,1341.,N,10020.,E...
$GPGGA,160330.60,1341.,N,10020.,E,1,...
```

It seemed like delimiter didn't work at all to separate the data into column by column. Hence, I tried with columns function based on number of fields from ($PUBX, 00). Here is the code when I add columns:

```
my_cols = ['MSG type', 'ID MSG', 'UTC','LAT', 'N/S', 'LONG', 'E/W', 'Alt', 'Status','hAcc', 'vAcc','SOG', 'COG', 'VD','HDOP', 'VDOP', 'TDOP', 'Svs', 'reserved', 'DR', 'CS', '<CR><LF>']

df = pd.read_csv(file, 'rb', header = None, na_filter = False, engine = 'python', index_col=False, names=my_cols)
```

and the result be like the picture below. The file becomes into one column in 'MSG type'.

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3dof.png)

My purpose after success to call this csv is to read rows only with combination between $PUBX, 00,... and one column of $PUBX, 04,... and write it to csv. But, I am still struggling how to separate the file into columns. Please advice me on this matter. Thank you very much.

Comment: At a glance your actual separator is a comma, not a tab. Try removing the `delimiter='\t'` argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.read_csv
```

is used for reading CSV(comma separated values) Files hence you don't need to specify a delimiter.

If you want to read a TSV (Tab separated values) File, you can use:

```
pd.read_table(filepath)
```

The default separator is tab

Answer (score 1):

Hat Tip to Ilja Everilä

@Hasanah Based on your code:

`df = pd.read_csv(file,'rb', delimiter ='\t', engine='python')`

`delimiter='\t'` tells pandas to separate the data into fields based on tab characters.

The default delimiter when pandas reads in csv files is a comma, so you should not need to define a delimiter:

`df = pd.read_csv(file,'rb', engine='python')`